# SQL Group two separate items in a column together in same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image: sql table]

Hi,

I have created a frame cutting list report for making cabinets report using SQL (see photo). I now need it so when the left stile and right stile are the same length and width, to have them in the same row and to count the QTY as 2... simply so the list isn't as long and it is easier for production to read.

Here is the SQL so far:

```
SELECT CxMaterial.Name        AS Material,
       Parts.[Cabinet ID],
       Parts.[Material ID],
       Count(Parts.[Part ID]) AS Qty,
       Parts.[Width String],
       Parts.[Length String],
       Parts.Description,
       Parts.[Part ID],
       CxUnitOfIssue.Name     AS UnitOfIssue
FROM   ((Parts
       INNER JOIN CxMaterial
               ON Parts.[Material ID] = CxMaterial.ID)
       INNER JOIN CxUnitOfIssue
               ON CxMaterial.UnitOfIssueID = CxUnitOfIssue.ID)
       INNER JOIN CxPart
               ON Parts.[Part ID] = CxPart.ID
WHERE  ( ( ( Parts.BuyOut ) = False )
         AND ( ( CxPart.PartSubClassID ) = 6 ) )
GROUP  BY CxMaterial.Name,
          Parts.[Material ID],
          Parts.[Cabinet ID],
          Parts.Width,
          Parts.[Width String],
          Parts.Length,
          Parts.[Length String],
          Parts.Description,
          Parts.[Part ID],
          CxUnitOfIssue.Name
ORDER  BY Parts.[Cabinet ID],
          CxMaterial.Name,
          Parts.[Part ID] BETWEEN 1 AND 2,
          Parts.[Part ID] BETWEEN 3 AND 6,
          Parts.[Width String] DESC,
          Parts.[Length String] DESC
```

Eg. For cabinet ID '2', the left and right stile are the same width and length... so I would like these in one row with 'QTY' 2 and 'Description' Left Stile & Right Stile. This is all done within Cabinet Vision Software.
Thank you.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: please avoid pasting pics , also provide desired output

Comment: @eshirvana should be clearer now thanks :)

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback, It's clear that the example provided is not the minimum standard. I will present you with a way that takes you to your "main request" without all the tables that are not available (neither structure nor sample data).

Let's start by referencing the script provided. There is a conceptual problem with the aggregation of the data. You cannot group by "Part ID" and expect one record for "Left Stile & Right Stile" since they both have different values. So with that in mind, take a look below:

```
DECLARE @SWAP TABLE ([CabinetId] INT NOT NULL, [MaterialId] INT NOT NULL, [Qty] INT NOT NULL, [WidthString] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [LengthString] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [Description] VARCHAR(250) NULL, [PartId] INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @SWAP ([CabinetId], [MaterialId], [Qty], [WidthString], [LengthString], [Description], [PartId])
VALUES (1, 36, 1, 25, 2295, 'Left Stile', 2)
      ,(1, 36, 1, 25, 2285, 'Right Stile', 1)
      ,(1, 36, 1, 60, 620, 'Top Rail', 3)
      ,(1, 36, 1, 40, 620, 'Bottom Rail', 4)
      ,(2, 36, 1, 25, 2285, 'Left Stile', 2)
      ,(2, 36, 1, 25, 2285, 'Right Stile', 1)
      ,(2, 36, 1, 60, 620, 'Top Rail', 3)
      ,(2, 36, 1, 40, 620, 'Bottom Rail', 4);

SELECT P1.[CabinetId]
      ,P1.[MaterialId]
      ,[Qty] = SUM(P1.[Qty])
      ,P1.[WidthString]
      ,P1.[LengthString]
      ,[Description] = CASE WHEN P2.[CabinetId] IS NULL THEN P1.[Description] ELSE 'Left Stile & Right Stile' END
      --,P1.[PartId] -- *** CONCEPTUAL PROBLEM. YOU CANNOT AGGREGATE BY < PartID > ***

FROM @SWAP AS P1
    LEFT JOIN @SWAP AS P2
    ON P2.[CabinetId] = P1.[CabinetId]
        AND P2.[MaterialId] = P1.[MaterialId]
        AND P2.[WidthString] = P1.[WidthString]
        AND P2.[LengthString] = P1.[LengthString]
        AND P2.[Description] <> P1.[Description]
        AND P2.[Description] IN ('Left Stile', 'Right Stile')

GROUP BY P1.[CabinetId]
        ,P1.[MaterialId]
        ,P1.[WidthString]
        ,P1.[LengthString]
        ,CASE WHEN P2.[CabinetId] IS NULL THEN P1.[Description] ELSE 'Left Stile & Right Stile' END
        --,P1.[PartId] -- *** CONCEPTUAL PROBLEM. YOU CANNOT AGGREGATE BY < PartID > ***
```

You can put this logic within a CTE and do the rest of the inner joins outside of the CTE.

Hope this idea takes you where you need to go... Happy Coding!